# Get TreeViewItem item when double clicking on item in a TreeView

Tags: javafx, treeview, eventhandler

I have a TreeView with a setOnMouseClicked event handler:

```
treeView.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
        if (event.getClickCount() == 2) {
            // Get TreeViewItem
        }
    }
}
```

How do I return the TreeViewItem which the double click was performed on? Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can use `event.getSource()` and then type cast it to TreeView.

Comment: That gives me the TreeView. How do I then get the TreeViewItem which was clicked on? getTreeItem() requires a row id as input.